# Error rate for Ads API calls in the last 30 days by this application is too high

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I build a Facebook app that uses the Facebook marketing API 
[Review error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmfyT.jpg)

But from the review I get back: "Our records show that the error rate for Ads API calls in the last 30 days by this application is too high. It is required that the application have a sufficiently low error rate before it is approved for Ads API Standard Access. Please review the criteria listed here for more information."

They send you to a page with the criteria, but there I can not find anything about it.
In the Facebook developers environment, I can not find anything on what the errors are
[Screenshot of the amount of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY1CW.jpg).

The app seems to run fine in development mode. The only errors I have seen are from the "Ad Account Level Rate Limit".

Does somebody had a similar problem and knows what the needed low error rate is, or what to do..

Comment: Hi Alex! Welcome to SO. Might be a silly question, but worth asking: have you tried changing the date range from "last 28 days" to one more broad? Let me know if you notice a difference with that. Cheers

Comment: Both yesterday, 7, 14, 28 and 90 give the same Marketing API Calls and the same Errors. This changed since yesterday, at that time there was a difference between 28 and 14.

Comment: I really do not understand it anymore. Now it shows for the last 7 days "6 marketing calls and 22 errors". How is this possible as yesterday it showed for yesterday alone 523 marketing calls and 22 errors. That should be part of the last 7 days. So suddenly more than 500 calls are gone..